# Make uib-typeahead work in a jHipster project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower, jhipster

I have created a project with jHipster 1.4.1. jHipster uses [angular-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) in its [1.3.3](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.3.3/) version for combining bootstrap components with angular directives. Now, I'm interested in displaying suggestion for a text input with previous given values, so I would like to use the `uib-typeahead` directive, but the problem is that the autocompletion is not getting shown. That's my code:

**bower.json**

```
{
"version": "0.0.0",
"name": "myApp",
"appPath": "src/main/webapp/",
"testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.32",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.8",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-translate": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.11.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootswatch": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.4.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "messageformat": "0.3.1",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.3.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.1.5",
    "ui-leaflet": "1.0.3",
    "angular-nvd3": "1.0.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.8"
},
"overrides": {
    "angular": {
        "dependencies": {
            "jquery": "3.1.0"
        }
    },
    "angular-cache-buster": {
        "dependencies": {
            "angular": "1.5.8"
        }
    },
    "angular-dynamic-locale": {
        "dependencies": {
            "angular": "1.5.8"
        }
    },
    "bootswatch": {
        "main": [
            "yeti/bootstrap.css"
        ]
    }
},
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.0"
}
```

}

**app.module.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module(
                    'myApp',
                    [ 'ngStorage', 'tmh.dynamicLocale',
                            'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngResource',
                            'ngCookies', 'ngAria', 'ngCacheBuster',
                            'ngFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap',
                            'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ui.router',
                            'infinite-scroll',
                            // jhipster-needle-angularjs-add-module JHipster
                            // will add
                            // new module here
                            'angular-loading-bar', 'ui-leaflet', 'nvd3',
                            'ui.bootstrap' ]).run(run);

    run.$inject = [ 'stateHandler', 'translationHandler' ];

    function run(stateHandler, translationHandler) {
        stateHandler.initialize();
        translationHandler.initialize();
    }
})();
```

**installation-dialog.html**

```
<!-- Not related code -->
<input type="text"
    class="form-control" name="business" id="field_business"
    ng-model="vm.installation.business"
    uib-typeahead="business for business in vm.businesses | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
    typeahead-no-results="noResults" />
<!-- Other not related code -->
```

I check that `vm.businesses` gets loaded with the values, but nothing gets displayed when I type into the input. No javascript errors are thrown.

Any idea what can I miss?

---

**EDIT**

**installation-dialog.controller.js**

```
InstallationSuggestion.query({
            field : 'business'
        }, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            vm.bussineses = result;
        });
```

The loaded businesses are shown in the console.

Comment: can you add the controller code ?

Comment: @svarog, done!! Still a bit difficult to provide an SSCCE with a tool like jHipster, which autogenerates all the boilerplate stuff.

Comment: what does the console prints ? is there any data? how is the data structured ?

Comment: `Array [ "one business", "" ]`. Just a string array. However, it seems more like a configuration problem, since even with no result, ` typeahead-no-results` should take care of it..

Comment: I wonder what's inside `InstallationSuggestion.query`, is there a `$http` that returns a promise?

Comment: It is, is there any problem with that?